# Statsmodel ARIMA multiple input

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I want to create my first (seasonal) ARIMA model but I find the Statsmodel ARIMA [documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html) insufficient. I lack information about calculating the prediction from multiple arrays (these are numpy arrays). These numpy arrays are series of values for each minute of a day. I want to make the prediction using data from each day of the last year.

Any advice/suggestions/links/hints on how to do that?

I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put your arrays into a single multidimensional array-like structure (Pandas DataFrame or NumPy array). Assume you have two arrays `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5, 6]`:

```
data = np.dstack([a, b])
model = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(data, order=(5,1,0)) # fits ARIMA(5,1,0) model
```

See [this blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/) for a more comprehensive example of creating an ARIMA model.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do what you say, it doesn't really work. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301997/multiple-inputs-into-statsmodels-arima-in-python). Any idea why that happens?