# Multiple inputs into Statsmodels ARIMA in Python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to fit a ARIMA model with multiple inputs. As long as the input was a single array it worked fine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235508/statsmodel-arima-multiple-input), I was adviced to put input arrays into a multidimensional array-like structure. So I did:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

data = np.dstack([a, b])
for p in range(6):
    for d in range(2):
        for q in range(4):
            order = (p,d,q)         
            try:
                model = ARIMA(data, order=(p,d,q))
                print("this works:{}, {}, {} ".format(p,d,q))
            except:
                pass
```

However, the output of this script was this:

```
   this works:0, 0, 0
```

Obviously, there is something wrong (if p,d,q are all 0 then it is not working at all). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Any advice that would point me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: @yeren1989 Have you found a solution to your problem? I have got exactly the same one. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to have enough 'degrees of freedom' when [modeling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68116/degrees-of-freedom-in-arima-model) using ARIMA.

So, the issue with your code is that np.dstack produces the shape of the array as (1,3,2) which means it has only one data element. You need a minimum number of 6 data elements to be able to run the ARIMA model with p-value 5.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116595/understanding-numpys-dstack-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) on array operations. I used np.vstack to produce as many as rows as possible.

Please run the code snippet below and you will understand.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
d = [7, 8]

data = np.vstack([a, b, c, d])

print(data.shape)
print(data)

for p in range(4):
    for d in range(1):
        for q in range(2):
            order = (p,d,q)    
            try:
                model = ARIMA(data, order=(p,d,q))
                print("this works:{}, {}, {} ".format(p,d,q))
            except:
                print(order)
                print('reached exception')
                pass
```